# VS2012 shortcut to properties windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is there a shortcut in VS2012 for opening Properties window of selected object? Something like Ctrl + Alt + L is for opening solution explorer.

Comment: Which properties? `F4`?

Comment: Both works, Alt + Enter and F4. F4 is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search shows us:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/21/properties-window-keyboard-shortcuts-vstiptool0111.aspx)